# Updating multiple documents using Java couchbase SDK

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++, couchbase-java-api

I am using java Couchbase sdk in my application. I want to update same path with same values for multiple documents. For example there is a key ***X*** with value ***Y*** in all these documents. I want to update the Key ***X*** to have the value ***Z***.

I am using the Async bucket's [query](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.3.1/com/couchbase/client/java/Bucket.html#query-com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlQuery-) method and the query that I am using looks like this-

***UPDATE default USE KEYS ["a","b","c"] SET X=Z***

default is the bucket name

a,b,c are the document keys that I want to update.

My question here is does the sdk guarantees that either all of these keys will be updated or none of them. How do I know if all the documents were updated correctly?

Answer (score 2):

N1QL doesn't support transactions (Atomicity is at document level not statement/multi statement level).
You should check out JAVA SDK transactions https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/distributed-acid-transactions-from-the-sdk.html